# Page refreshing multiple times while clicking on next or previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, pagination

I've a couple of pop-up to display the user list which would display 10 results per page, which is working fine.

I'm getting the page nos. from the java servlet in the JSON. 
While, clicking on the next button, at times the page is refreshed multiple times.

Here's the code.

```js
var currentPageNo = 0; // Keep track of currently displayed page

  $('.next-btn').click(function(){ // Give buttons an ID (include them in HTML as hidden)
   userList(currentPageNo+10);
   adminList(currentPageNo+10);
   
  });
  $('.prev-btn').click(function(){
   userList(currentPageNo-10);
   adminList(currentPageNo-10);
  });

  function userList(pageNo) {
   var resType="userList";
   createTable(resType,pageNo);
  }
  
  function adminList(pageNo) {
   var resType="adminList";
   createTable(resType,pageNo);
  }

  function createTable(resType, pageNo) {
   // Update global variable
   currentPageNo = pageNo; 
   // Set visibility of the "prev" button:
   $('.prev-btn').toggle(pageNo > 0);
   // Ask one record more than needed, to determine if there are more records after this page:
   $.getJSON("https://api.randomuser.me/?results=11&start="+pageNo, function(data) {
    $('#datatable tr:has(td)').empty();
    // Check if there's an extra record which we do not display, 
    // but determines that there is a next page
    $('.next-btn').toggle(data.results.length > 10);
    // Slice results, so 11th record is not included:
    data.results.slice(0, 10).forEach(function (record, i) { // add second argument for numbering records
     var json = JSON.stringify(record);
     $('#datatable').append(
      $('<tr>').append(
       $('<td>').append(
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'checkbox')
           .addClass('selectRow')
           .val(json),
        (i+1+pageNo) // display row number
       ),
       $('<td>').append(
        $('<a>').attr('href', record.picture.thumbnail)
          .addClass('imgurl')
          .attr('target', '_blank')
          .text(record.name.first)
       ),
       $('<td>').append(record.dob)
      )
     );
    });
    // Show the prev and/or buttons
    
    
   }).fail(function(error) {
    console.log("**********AJAX ERROR: " + error);
   });            
  }

  var savedData = []; // The objects as array, so to have an order.

  function saveData(){
   var errors = [];
   // Add selected to map
   $('input.selectRow:checked').each(function(count) {
    // Get the JSON that is stored as value for the checkbox
    var obj = JSON.parse($(this).val());
    // See if this URL was already collected (that's easy with Set)
    if (savedData.find(record => record.picture.thumbnail === obj.picture.thumbnail)) {
     errors.push(obj.name.first);
    } else {
     // Append it
     savedData.push(obj);
    }
   });
   refreshDisplay();
   if (errors.length) {
    alert('The following were already selected:\n' + errors.join('\n'));
   }
  }

  function refreshDisplay() {
   $('.container').html('');
   savedData.forEach(function (obj) {
    // Reset container, and append collected data (use jQuery for appending)
    $('.container').append(
     $('<div>').addClass('parent').append(
      $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Name: '),
      obj.name.first + ' ' + obj.name.last,
      $('<br>'), // line-break between name & pic
      $('<img>').addClass('myLink').attr('src', obj.picture.thumbnail), $('<br>'),
      $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Date of birth: '),
      obj.dob, $('<br>'),
      $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Address: '), $('<br>'),
      obj.location.street, $('<br>'),
      obj.location.city + ' ' + obj.location.postcode, $('<br>'),
      obj.location.state, $('<br>'),
      $('<button>').addClass('removeMe').text('Delete'),
      $('<button>').addClass('top-btn').text('Swap with top'),
      $('<button>').addClass('down-btn').text('Swap with down')
     ) 
    );
   })
   // Clear checkboxes:
   $('.selectRow').prop('checked', false);
   handleEvents();
  }

  function logSavedData(){
   // Convert to JSON and log to console. You would instead post it
   // to some URL, or save it to localStorage.
   console.log(JSON.stringify(savedData, null, 2));
  }

  function getIndex(elem) {
   return $(elem).parent('.parent').index();
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.removeMe', function() {
   // Delete this from the saved Data
   savedData.splice(getIndex(this), 1);
   // And redisplay
   refreshDisplay();
  });

  /* Swapping the displayed articles in the result list */
  $(document).on('click', ".down-btn", function() {
   var index = getIndex(this);
   // Swap in memory
   savedData.splice(index, 2, savedData[index+1], savedData[index]);
   // And redisplay
   refreshDisplay();
  });

  $(document).on('click', ".top-btn", function() {
   var index = getIndex(this);
   // Swap in memory
   savedData.splice(index-1, 2, savedData[index], savedData[index-1]);
   // And redisplay
   refreshDisplay();
  });
   
  /* Disable top & down buttons for the first and the last article respectively in the result list */
  function handleEvents() {
   $(".top-btn, .down-btn").prop("disabled", false).show();
   $(".parent:first").find(".top-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
   $(".parent:last").find(".down-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#showExtForm-btn').click(function(){
    $('#extUser').toggle();
   });
   $("#extUserForm").submit(function(e){
    addExtUser();
    return false;
     });
  });

  function addExtUser() {
   var extObj = {
    name: {
     title: "mr", // No ladies? :-)
     first: $("#name").val(),
     // Last name ?
    },
    dob: $("#dob").val(),
    picture: {
     thumbnail: $("#myImg").val()
    },
    location: { // maybe also ask for this info?
    }
   };
   savedData.push(extObj);
   refreshDisplay(); // Will show some undefined stuff (location...)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userList" onclick="userList(0)">User List</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="logSavedData()">Get Saved Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adminList" onclick="adminList(0)">User Admin</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extUser">Open External Form</button>

       <div class="modal fade" id="userList" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      
        
        <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">User List</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="table-responsive">
                                  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable">
         <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
         </tr>
        </table>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prev-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
        </div>
       </div>
                                <hr/>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="saveData()">Save selected</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-less-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <br />
        </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="modal fade" id="adminList" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Admin List</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="table-responsive">
                                  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable">
         <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
         </tr>
        </table>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prev-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
        </div>
       </div>
                                <hr/>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="saveData()">Save selected</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-less-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <br />
        </div>
      </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="modal fade" id="extUser" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      
        <!-- External User-->
        <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title">Add External User</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <form class="form-horizontal" id="extUserForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="myImg">Image:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myImg" name="myImg" required>
          </div>
        </div>
                
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="dob">DOB:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
         <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-external-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
         </form>
       </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
       </div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Note that calling both *userList* and *adminList* in the click handlers will make the *currentPageNo* increase with 20 in the admin list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $('.next-btn').unbind("click").on("click",function(){ // Give buttons an ID (include them in HTML as hidden)
         userList(currentPageNo+10);
         adminList(currentPageNo+10);
        });
    $('.prev-btn').unbind("click").on("click",function(){
        userList(currentPageNo-10);
        adminList(currentPageNo-10);
    });
```

I think `click event` is getting binded multiple times which is making multiple refresh, so `unbind` and then add event onclick.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works for me!

Comment: `unbind` is not necessary, as at the time this code is executed there is no handler bound yet, and this code is only executed on page load. Note also that `unbind` is deprecated since version 3.0. If needed, you would use `off` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Next button event listener. Maybe the same for Previous too:

```
$('.next-btn').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();         
userList(currentPageNo+10);
        adminList(currentPageNo+10);

    });
```