# Saving new JSON received through AJAX to an existing array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, dynamic

I'm creating a JSON out of the displayed dynamic data and sending it through AJAX to some url.

Now, I'm receiving the same saved JSON earlier, through AJAX and changing my display accordingly. But for some reason I'm getting an error that 'savedData.forEach' is not a function.

Am I doing anything wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    displaySavedData();
});

function displaySavedData() {
 $('.container').html('');
    $.getJSON("/def/someData/mySaved.json", function(data) {
  savedData = data;
 refreshDisplay();
    }).fail(function(error) {
            console.log("AJAX ERROR: " + error);
    });
}

var currentPageNo = 0; // Keep track of currently displayed page

// Select button that is descendant of userList
$('#userList .prev-btn').click(function(){ 
    userList(currentPageNo-10);
});
$('#userList .next-btn').click(function(){ 
    userList(currentPageNo+10);
});
$('#adminList .prev-btn').click(function(){ 
    adminList(currentPageNo-10);
});
$('#adminList .next-btn').click(function(){ 
    adminList(currentPageNo+10);
});

function userList(pageNo) {
    var resType="userList";
    createTable(resType,pageNo);
}

function adminList(pageNo) {
    var resType="adminList";
    createTable(resType,pageNo);
}

function createTable(resType, pageNo) {
    // Update global variable
    currentPageNo = pageNo; 
    // Set visibility of the correct "prev" button:
    $('#' + resType + ' .prev-btn').toggle(pageNo > 0);
    // Ask one record more than needed, to determine if there are more records after this page:
    $.getJSON("https://api.randomuser.me/?results=11&resType="+resType + "&pageIndex=" + pageNo, function(data) {
        var $table = $('#' + resType + ' table');
        ('tr:has(td)', $table).empty();
        // Check if there's an extra record which we do not display, 
        // but determines that there is a next page
        $('#' + resType + ' .next-btn').toggle(data.results.length > 10);
        // Slice results, so 11th record is not included:
        data.results.slice(0, 10).forEach(function (record, i) { // add second argument for numbering records
            var json = JSON.stringify(record);
            $table.append(
                $('<tr>').append(
                    $('<td>').append(
                        $('<input>').attr('type', 'checkbox')
                                    .addClass('selectRow')
                                    .val(json),
                        (i+1+pageNo) // display row number
                    ),
                    $('<td>').append(
                        $('<a>').attr('href', record.picture.thumbnail)
                                .addClass('imgurl')
                                .attr('target', '_blank')
                                .text(record.name.first)
                    ),
                    $('<td>').append(record.dob)
                )
            );
        });
        // Show the prev and/or buttons
        
        
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log("**********AJAX ERROR: " + error);
    });            
}

var savedData = []; // The objects as array, so to have an order.

function saveData(){
    var errors = [];
    // Add selected to map
    $('input.selectRow:checked').each(function(count) {
        // Get the JSON that is stored as value for the checkbox
        var obj = JSON.parse($(this).val());
        // See if this URL was already collected (that's easy with Set)
        if (savedData.find(record => record.picture.thumbnail === obj.picture.thumbnail)) {
            errors.push(obj.name.first);
        } else {
            // Append it
            savedData.push(obj);
        }
    });
    refreshDisplay();
    if (errors.length) {
        alert('The following were already selected:\n' + errors.join('\n'));
    }
}

function refreshDisplay() {
    $('.container').html('');
    savedData.forEach(function (obj) {
        // Reset container, and append collected data (use jQuery for appending)
        $('.container').append(
            $('<div>').addClass('parent').append(
                $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Name: '),
                obj.name.first + ' ' + obj.name.last,
                $('<br>'), // line-break between name & pic
                $('<img>').addClass('myLink').attr('src', obj.picture.thumbnail), $('<br>'),
                $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Date of birth: '),
                obj.dob, $('<br>'),
                $('<label>').addClass('dataLabel').text('Address: '), $('<br>'),
                obj.location.street, $('<br>'),
                obj.location.city + ' ' + obj.location.postcode, $('<br>'),
                obj.location.state, $('<br>'),
                $('<button>').addClass('removeMe').text('Delete'),
                $('<button>').addClass('top-btn').text('Swap with top'),
                $('<button>').addClass('down-btn').text('Swap with down')
            ) 
        );
    })
    // Clear checkboxes:
    $('.selectRow').prop('checked', false);
    handleEvents();
}

function logSavedData(){
    // Convert to JSON and log to console. You would instead post it
    // to some URL, or save it to localStorage.
    $.ajax({
        url:"/abc/saveAndUpdare",
        type: "POST",
        data:savedData,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
         alert("Data saved successfully!");
        }
    });
}

function getIndex(elem) {
    return $(elem).parent('.parent').index();
}

$(document).on('click', '.removeMe', function() {
    // Delete this from the saved Data
    savedData.splice(getIndex(this), 1);
    // And redisplay
    refreshDisplay();
});

/* Swapping the displayed articles in the result list */
$(document).on('click', ".down-btn", function() {
    var index = getIndex(this);
    // Swap in memory
    savedData.splice(index, 2, savedData[index+1], savedData[index]);
    // And redisplay
    refreshDisplay();
});

$(document).on('click', ".top-btn", function() {
    var index = getIndex(this);
    // Swap in memory
    savedData.splice(index-1, 2, savedData[index], savedData[index-1]);
    // And redisplay
    refreshDisplay();
});
    
/* Disable top & down buttons for the first and the last article respectively in the result list */
function handleEvents() {
    $(".top-btn, .down-btn").prop("disabled", false).show();
    $(".parent:first").find(".top-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
    $(".parent:last").find(".down-btn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showExtForm-btn').click(function(){
        $('#extUser').toggle();
    });
    $("#extUserForm").submit(function(e){
        addExtUser();
        return false;
   });
});

function addExtUser() {
    var extObj = {
        name: {
            title: "mr", // No ladies? :-)
            first: $("#name").val(),
            // Last name ?
        },
        dob: $("#dob").val(),
        picture: {
            thumbnail: $("#myImg").val()
        },
        location: { // maybe also ask for this info?
        }
    };
    savedData.push(extObj);
    refreshDisplay(); // Will show some undefined stuff (location...)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userList" onclick="userList(0)">User List</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="logSavedData()">Get Saved Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adminList" onclick="adminList(0)">User Admin</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#extUser">Open External Form</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="userList" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    
      
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">User List</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prev-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
            <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="saveData()">Save selected</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-less-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="adminList" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Admin List</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="datatable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary prev-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
            <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="saveData()">Save selected</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-less-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="extUser" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    
      <!-- External User-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add External User</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" id="extUserForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="name">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="myImg">Image:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myImg" name="myImg" required>
              </div>
            </div>
                                            
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="dob">DOB:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">        
              <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reset</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close-external-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "resultset": [
    {
        "title": "Google",
        "CreationDate": "Mar 14, 2017 4:06:00 PM",
        "location": "USA",
        "path": "www.google.com",
        "image": "www.google.com/images/logo.jpg"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "Global",
        "CreationDate": "Mar 14, 2017 4:06:00 PM",
        "location": "Global",
        "path": "www.abc.com",
        "image": "www.abc.com/images/logo.jpg"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "Yahoo",
        "CreationDate": "Mar 14, 2017 4:06:00 PM",
        "location": "Europe",
        "path": "www.yahoo.com",
        "image": "www.yahoo.com/images/logo.jpg"
    },
    {
        "title": "Amazon",
        "CreationDate": "Mar 14, 2017 4:06:00 PM",
        "location": "Europe",
        "path": "www.amazon.com",
        "image": "www.amazon.com/images/logo.jpg"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "XYZ",
        "CreationDate": "Mar 14, 2017 4:06:00 PM",
        "location": "Europe",
        "path": "www.xyz.com",
        "image": "www.xyz.com/images/logo.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you have to pass some function as parameter inside the savedData.forEach(someFunction).

Comment: at which point the error is popping up, give more details about the error please ,or paste the entire stack trace of the error . May be an initialization problem .

Comment: How do I pass that function here? Sorry, I'm new to jquery..

Comment: Could you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));` inside the `$.getJSON` callback, before calling `refreshDisplay`, and add that output (or a sample of it) to your question? Obviously it is not an array as you expect.

Comment: Ok, I'd added sample output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the returned data, it is not an array, but a plain object with a *resultset* property. You get the error on `forEach`, because plain objects do not have the `forEach` method.

You need to get the value of the object's *resultset* property which *does* contain the array of your interest:

```
function displaySavedData() {
    $('.container').html('');
    $.getJSON("/def/someData/mySaved.json", function(data) {
        savedData = data.resultset; // <------
        refreshDisplay();
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log("AJAX ERROR: " + error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, It works perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello Sir, could you please help me? I've tried to build on the existing logic to update the user using a form. But I'm stuck. Could you please take a look into this question? Any help is appreciated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627969/update-a-user-using-a-modal-form-and-display-updated-details